# What does Python exactly do when it calls a function from another module?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python and my shallow thought is that when Python calls a function in another file, it just copies the code block of that function. But I think this is not true, because, think of this specific situation:

**in my main.py**

```
from functions import function_a

function_a()
```

**in functions.py module**

```
import sys

def function_a():
    sys.exit()
```

The problem here is that **I must import sys in function.py**. If the mechanism was copying code block, then I suppose I would be able to import sys in main.py? Why do I have to import the necessary module (e.g. sys) at the time of definition, rather than at the time of execution?

And I would like to further expand this question by considering another situation:

**in my main.py**

```
from classes import ClassA

from functions import function_a


instance = ClassA()

function_a(instance)
```

**in functions.py module**

```
def function_a(instance):
    instance.method_a()
```

Here in *functions.py*, in the definition of *function_a*, I use *method_a* which is an instance method in ClassA. But **I don't have to import ClassA in functions.py**, instead, I import ClassA in main.py. So why this is somewhat in the opposite way?

Any thoughts or references will be appreciated.

Comment: You misunderstand python's import system. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html.

Comment: "it just copies the code block of that function." no, that isn't what happens at all. In any case, imports load modules and affect which names are accessible in which namespace. That is the issue here.